# EntityFramework 5.0 : marking a navigation property as "modified"

Tags: entity-framework-5, navigation-properties

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and I'd like to know if there is a way  to mark a navigation property as modified.

I saw that this can be done with a "normal" property, this way :

```
context.Entry(blog).Property(u => u.Name).IsModified = true
```

Is there something similar for collection ? :

```
context.Entry(blog).Collection..???
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, because in the end the modified properties are used to build update statements. Since update statements only modify primitive properties there is no way to mark navigation properties as modified.

You have to mark properties in the `Collection` object itself as modified (or objects in `Collection` if it is a collection of objects).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
The problem is that I had to desactivated the autoDetectChanges of my EntityContainer (to speed up access to my database). 
So changing the state of the entities in my collection is not sufficient for the framework to detect that this collection has been modified. That's why I wanted to explicitly "tell him" that the collection has changed and that theses changes have to be saved in the data base....

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
RepositoryContext.Attach(entity);
var dbEntry = this.RepositoryContext.Entry(entity);
dbEntry.Collection("Addresses").IsModified = true;
```

Comment: So what, I have encountered this problem yesterday, and found a solution and shared it to help anyone, not everyone is champion here!!!